# Understand starmap_async() in multiprocessing programmation

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

This above code works fine but I don't fully understand it:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,Manager
from itertools import chain

def calculate_primes():
    ncore = 2
    N = 50
    with Manager() as manager:
        input = manager.Queue()
        output = manager.Queue()

        with Pool(ncore) as p:
            it = p.starmap_async(find_prime,[(input,output)])
            for r in chunks(range(1,N),10): # chunks the list into sublists
                input.put(r)
            input.put(None)
            it.wait() # if here: doesn't work! Why?
            output.put(None)
            it.wait() # mut be here to works fine!!

        res = list(chain(*list(iter(output.get,None))))
    return res
```

find_prime() is a function that returns a prime numbers list.

When p.starmap_async(somefunction,[(input,output)]) instruction is really executed?
Why does this function need it.wait() instruction to be executed?

If no it.wait() instruction in function => it returns empty list []
If it.wait() instruction located before inut.put(None) => it seemns an infinite loop that I must kill.

Why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you describe at last the signature of `find_prime`?. This piece of code runs only one process at a time, and clearly do not profits of the `map` part of  `starmap_async`, which removes the burden of setting up queues.

Comment: def find_prime_worker(input, output):
for chunk in iter(input.get,None):
primes_found = list(filter(check_prime,chunk))
output.put(primes_found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of `map` functions is to remove the burden of setting up queues from the programmer, reading from the queues and assemble the responses in order. Your code could be simplified to:

```py
def find_prime(chunk):
    primes_found = list(filter(check_prime, chunk))
    return primes_found

def calculate_primes():
    ncore = 2
    N = 50
    with Pool(ncore) as p:
        res = p.map(find_prime, chunks(range(1,N), 10))
    return res
```

(where `chunks` does what I guess it does)

The original code has the following issues:

- When you call `p.starmap_async(find_prime,[(input,output)])` you are passing a lenght-1 iterable, so only one process will be used. You can use `[(input,output)] * ncore` instead to use `ncore` processes.
- If you **do** use more than one process, only one of them would get the `None` value from the queue, and the other one would wait forever. This bug was hidden by the previous one.
- `it.wait()` waits forever for the process to finish. If you put it *before* `input.put(None)`, the spawned process is waiting for a `None` value to finish and the main process is waiting for the spawned process to finish: there is a deadlock (note that the question says one thing "t.wait() instruction located before `input.put(None)`" but the code says another thing).
- As you are using the `async` version, you must `wait` for the process to finish. If you don't call `wait`, you put a `None` in the `output` queue immediately, before any result has been fed by the spawned processes. Thus, the first value removed from the queue is `None`, signaling the end of the iterations for the `iter` call: you end up with an empty list. Moreover, you exit the `with Pool(ncore) as p:` while the processes are still running and (I guess) they are terminated.

Passing chunks of data to process instead of one by one **is** a good idea: that is what the `chunksize` parameter of the `map` functions is for. Nevertheless, it would not be useful with your current implementation of `find_prime`

Comment: Hi,  a great big thanks! Thanks for the time you took.